# RSS/Atom feed for search terms

Tags: feature-request, rss

Is there a way to get an RSS / Atom feed for questions matching a particular search term?

It would be nice to get able to get:

```
http://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=$FOOBAR
```

as a feed in my blog-reader, so that if there's a question or comment referencing software I help maintain, I can go take a look quickly, rather than stumbling upon it.

If it doesn't exist now but is implemented in the future, can the threshold reputation for using the feature please be set <= 1000, so I can use it?  :)

Thanks,
-Phil

Comment: Being able to specify multiple search terms in a single query would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't available and I don't think it's going to be made available.

> Searches are too performance intensive to be RSS feeds.
>
> If you can't express your search as a set of tags ([we support and/or
>   in tags, see the
>   blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/)),
>   which *does* have an RSS feed, I humbly submit you aren't trying hard
>   enough. :)

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches)